# Wordpress: Use foreach twice in an a custom post type args array

Tags: php, wordpress

In the events calendar for wordpress they have a subscribe to google calendar on each category page.  Im trying to output a list of all categories and the related subscribe buttons to display on the main calendar page. Desired layout https://www.screencast.com/t/ksIt2UEbt
Getting the categories is easy using the following code.

```
<?php
   $args = array(
               'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
               'orderby' => 'name',
               'order'   => 'ASC'
           );

   $cats = get_categories($args);

   foreach($cats as $cat) {
?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ?>">
           <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
      </a>
<?php
   }
?>
```

The individual category pages use this code to create a subscribe button.

```
<?php foreach ( $items as $item ) : ?>
                <?php $this->template( 'components/subscribe-links/item', [ 'item' => $item ] ); ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can foreach ( $items as $item ) and foreach($cats as $cat) work together to grab the cat name and the subscribe button?

Comment: _"The individual category pages use this code to create a subscribe button."_ - "a" button? Looks rather like multiple, or what else would the loop be for. What _is_ `$items` in that place?

Comment: Each button pops up a list to subscribe to google, microsoft, or ICS.  It is confusing why they use item.

Comment: But what is the connection between the categories, and these items? Does each category have its own set of items, and if so, how are they determined / selected?